# Can I ask questions about my own Sci-Fi ideas?

Tags: discussion

I have been thinking about some topics and ideas and I think I have come up with some interesting ideas. Can I ask questions regarding those topics? Note that those questions won't refer to movies, novels or games explicitly.

Answer (score 9):

From [the FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq):

> **What kind of questions can I ask here?**
>
> Science Fiction and Fantasy - Stack Exchange is for questions targeted towards science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. This includes questions about:
>
> - Plot, character, or setting explanations
> - Historical or societal context of a work
> - Behind-the-scenes and fandom information
> - Story identification
> - Franchise/series reading or viewing order

Your question here is a little vague, but I'm leaning towards saying it'd be off-topic. Depending on your specific questions, you may find the [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/) or [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) StackExchanges to be better suited.

Comment: So the questions that should be asked here must refer to some 'work' if they are to be accepted?

Comment: @ChosenTorture I think it'd help if you fleshed out your question a bit. It's unclear if you're asking questions about the writing process, which Writers.SE is better for.  We do take questions about genre conventions here, but I don't know if your question is talking about that sort of thing.

Comment: @Keen For example, I am trying to construct a futuristic modified totalitarian society and would like to have suggestions about the construct of government that I envision which involves 'AI Bots'. Are such questions acceptable?

Comment: No. There's no definitive answer to that question, as you describe it. Something like that would be fine in the chat rooms, but no SE site would deem that as on-topic.

Comment: I agree with @phantom42 -- it should be a topic that would be good for [Mos Eisley, SFF.SE's chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) or the Writers.SE chatroom.

Comment: For some aspects, your questions might be great for WorldBuilding SE.